# how to fill MVC dropdownlist via javascript

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-select

Good morning, i have a view that is connected to a view model, it has 3 parts a general information that is a simple model, a address model that is a List<> and a telephone model that is a list too, on the view model. My problem is that on the new customer view, the above view, the address and telephone model is empty, when i give the user the opportunity to add address and telephone the model is empty, so when i need to fill 2 dropdownlists with the above data the page is already loaded. So my question is how can i "refresh" the dropdownlist data to fill from a ViewBag that holds the above data?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When the user clicks on the `Add New Address` button you could perform an AJAX call to a controller action that will return a partial view containing the template of an address that will get added the DOM. Steven Sanderson illustrated the concept in his very excellent [`Editing a variable length list in ASP.NET MVC`](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/12/22/editing-a-variable-length-list-of-items-in-aspnet-mvc/) blog post.

As an alternative to using AJAX you could also do this using a pure client side approach. For example you could use a templating javascript framework such as [`knockoutjs`](http://knockoutjs.com/). Steven Sanderson also covered this approach in [`his blog post`](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/07/12/editing-a-variable-length-list-knockout-style/).

Comment: when the user adds an address i already return a partialview, can i return 2 partialviews by calling 2 controller actions?

Comment: No, you can't return 2 partial views. One partial view containing the template of an address item should be enough. Please read the article I have linked in my answer for a very detailed explanation of how to achieve this.

Comment: Is there a way i can "refresh" a viewmodel, it has a single object and 2 list of objects properties in it? Without reloading the whole page and loosing the data that it has? thanks again.